# What type of database is this application accessing?

Tags: vba, etl, database

I have a client application that needs to be reverse-engineered and rewritten. It has rich client implemented on VB (I think) and a database as a file and reusing this database is the requirement of the project.

I need to check this database and extract data if needed. The problem is that I have no idea how to do that. I know is the app uses **msvbvm60.dll** and the database file has the extention **.sys**. I think it worth checking the content of the file but it is huge(3GB) and I'm afraid a specific tool is required.

Could someone please help me find out what type of database this file is so I can connect to and review it?

Comment: msvbvm60.dll is a core file in VB6 redistributable, and confirm that it does indeed use that language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [filext](http://filext.com/file-extension/SYS):

- PDP-10 File
- PlayStation 2 Icon
- SYGRAPH/SYSTAT/SPSS/PC (Data File)
- System Configuration
- System Device Driver
- Unknown Apple II File (found on Golden Orchard Apple II CD Rom)

It may also be possible to use a file editor, such as [xvi32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) to look at the file and see if there is any text in the file that may identify the database

Answer (score 0):

The .sys file is probably a custom format created by the VB application.  If you don't have the source, you will need to analyze the data in the .sys file using a binary dump utility and re-construct the format.   On Linux, I used 'od' for this type of work.  Once you can figure out the file format, you can migrate it the whatever format your new application is using.